# How to get/set user group/role for AWS cognito web identity users

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito

Is it possible to get/set any user group /role for AWS cognito Web identities (Google /facebook  ) users ?

Answer (score 0):

If you directly link Google/Facebook to your Cognito Userpool (and not as an Auth provider in Identity Pool), then this is possible. In fact, all external users are automatically replicated in your Userpool based on your attribute mapping and are added to an auto-created Userpool group named UserpoolID_Providername eg. us_east_1_xxxx_Facebook. Now, once created automatically, you can set a role for these groups and all user tokens will have this role.

See [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-social.html) doc.  And don't forget to [map](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-specifying-attribute-mapping.html) the attributes too.

Comment: If you directly link Google/Facebook to your Cognito Userpool Can you please let me know the steps for this ?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-social.html

Comment: yes, I followed those steps. and i can get a token from the google. and i can use this token to getawscredentials. my problem is i dont get the user role information there.

Comment: it won't be in the google token, get a Cognito token using Google signin and it will have the role

Comment: export function getAwsCredentials(userToken, type) {
  let authenticator = '';
  if (type == 'CUSTOM') {
    authenticator = `cognito-idp.${config.cognito
      .REGION}.amazonaws.com/${config.cognito.USER_POOL_ID}`;
  }
  else if (type == 'GOOGLE') {
    authenticator = 'accounts.google.com';
  }

  AWS.config.update({ region: config.cognito.REGION });

  AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: config.cognito.IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
    Logins: {
      [authenticator]: userToken
    }
  });
  return AWS.config.credentials.getPromise();}

Comment: I use the above method, but i do not get any user roles ??

Comment: In IdentityPools, for Cognito Userpool set 'Choose role with tokens' option instead of 'Use default role'. Also, decode your Cognito (& not Google) Id token at jwt.io. Do you see any role info?

Comment: I added a screen shot of my user pool and how can i get the cognito token from the google token ?